# On the existence of a certain real measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm stuck on the following problem :

Does there exist a real borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^n d\mu = e^{-n^2}$$
for all $n \geq 1$ ?

Does anyone have any hint?

Thank you

Comment: Is $\mu$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem

Comment: Theo's link only seems to deal with the positive case.  If you're interested in necessary and sufficient conditions in the general case, a good reference is chapter 3 of Widder's *The Laplace transform*.  (Note that real finite measures correspond to functions of bounded variation, and Widder's exposition uses Stieltjes integrals.)

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu$ is supposed to be positive, then $\langle f,g\rangle=\int fgd\mu$ defines a pre-[inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) on the real vector space of polynomial functions on $[0,1]$.  [Gramian matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) with respect to this inner product must be positive semidefinite.  For example, 
$\begin{bmatrix}
\langle x,x\rangle & \langle x,x^2\rangle \\
\langle x^2,x\rangle & \langle x^2,x^2\rangle
\end{bmatrix}$ should be positive semidefinite.

Comment: yes. And already the Gram matrix based on $(1,x)$ (instead of your $(x,x^2)$) is not.

Comment: @Didier: I don't know; I used $(x,x^2)$ because the problem says $n\geq 1$.  But yes, my point was that it is not possible in the positive case.  I only wish the OP had responded with clarification.

Comment: in fact you were right, one cannot conclude from the Gram matrix based on $1$ and $x$ because the OP does not specify the total mass of $\mu$. Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 1):

By the simple argument given by Jonas and explained in the Wiki page Theo referred to, there can exist no such *positive* measure $\mu$ since, using the notation below, $M_2M_4<(M_3)^2$.

As regards the existence of a *signed* measure $\mu$ of bounded variation on the interval $[0,1]$ with a given sequence of moments 
$$
M_n=\displaystyle\int_0^1x^n\mathrm{d}\mu(x),
$$
it might be worthwhile, following Jonas's hint, to recall the result stated in chapter 3 section 2 of Widder's *The Laplace transform*: such a measure $\mu$ exists iff the sequence $(S_n)$ is bounded, where for every nonnegative $n$,
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left|\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i{k\choose i}M_{n-i}\right|.
$$
Hence to determine if $(S_n)$ is bounded or not when $M_n=\mathrm{e}^{-n^2}$ for every $n\ge1$ would give the answer.